# Render profiling in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, performance

Sometimes, when I add a shader node render times for a single object are reasonable but, whenever I try to render sets of said object (e.g. tree --> forest) rendering takes up days or even weeks for relatively small scenes (garden with ~100 trees). Is there a way to profile render so that I might have a clue which node's pegging the (C)GPU?

Comment: It'd be important to note whether those trees are linked to the same mesh (eg. duplicated with Alt+D) or not but it really depends on many more factors other than only nodes (shader ones I think in this case). Calculating global illumination between different objects, shadows, whether one visible behind another one - only some of those problems

Comment: They are hair particles added over a procedurally generated mesh.